# continuous functions between glued spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Write $\mathbb{S}^1$ as the union of its upper and lower hemispheres $D_+,D_-$, with $D_+\cap D_-=\mathbb{S}^0\times(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Given a map $f:\mathbb{S}^0\mapsto GL_n(\mathbb{R})$, i can construct a space $$E_f:= (D_+\times\mathbb R^n) \sqcup (D_-\times\mathbb R^n) / \sim$$ by identifying $(x,v) \in \mathbb{S}^0\times\{t\}$ with $(x,f(x)(v)) \in \mathbb{S}^0\times\{-t\}$.

How would i show that a particular function
$$F:E_f\mapsto E_g$$ is continuous? Of course the definition of continuity gives us, that the inverse image of an open set has to be an open set. Isn't the following function then continuous, if $f\circ g^{-1}= id_\mathbb{R^n}$:
\begin{align*}
(x,v) \in \mathbb{S}^1\setminus(D_+\cap D_-)\times\mathbb{R}^n &\mapsto (x,v)\\
(x,v) = (x,f(x)(v)) \in D_+\cap D_- \times\mathbb{R}^n&\mapsto (x,v) = (x,g(x)(v))
\end{align*}

Since for a open subset of $U\subset E_g$ we have 
\begin{align*}
F^{-1}(U) &= F^{-1}(U\cap(\mathbb{S}^1\setminus(D_+\cap D_-)\times\mathbb{R}^n)\cup(U\cap (D_+\cap D_-) \times\mathbb{R}^n))\\
&=F^{-1}(U\cap(\mathbb{S}^1\setminus(D_+\cap D_-)\times\mathbb{R}^n))\cup F^{-1}(U\cap (D_+\cap D_-) \times\mathbb{R}^n)\\
\text{is firstly:}&=U\cap(\mathbb{S}^1\setminus(D_+\cap D_-)\times\mathbb{R}^n)\cup U\cap (D_+\cap D_-) \times\mathbb{R}^n\\
\text{but also:}&=U\cap(\mathbb{S}^1\setminus(D_+\cap D_-)\times\mathbb{R}^n)\cup U\cap (D_+\cap D_-) \times f\circ g^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)\\
&= U
\end{align*}

So in order for the two to be actually the same, this $f\circ g^{-1}= id_\mathbb{R^n}$ has to hold right?

My question is: is this even remotely correct? and can I extend this to $f\circ g^{-1}\sim id_\mathbb{R^n}$